# Why doesn't my ceiling fan's LED light kit work?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, led

Casablanca 6 speed ceiling fan. The remote control is communicating with the receiver.

The fan can be controlled at all speeds. The light does not come on.

I will check the voltage coming out of the receiver. I have not yet checked to see if the two blue wires have good connection.

What is the expected voltage from the light (blue) wire from a ceiling fan receiver?

Comment: AustinGary, please share more information about your hardware in your post. We're guessing in the dark here.

Comment: Austin,  we can **not provide an informed answer** unless you supply us with information. Please use the **edit button** to add as much info about the unit you have and how/what you have done to get to this point.

Comment: Is this a new install or a problem that just started with an exciting unit?  How is it wired? What diagnostics have you done? *Isherwood: i see what you did with that "guessing in the dark" comment. ;)* It's still a little dark in here, more light needs to be shed on the problem at hand.

Comment: We can guess 120v if in the US 240v in many other countries see we are still guessing.